# Network Drive Letter or UNC Path for file path

Tags: visual-foxpro, unc, file-not-found, network-drive

I am providing application support for a legacy VisualFoxPro application. The users of the application seem to have problem running a report. The report runs a comparison between data from the database ( MS SQL SERVER) and local file (xxPAY.dbf) and displays the report. The user interface for running the report requires the user to input a month and year and the path for xxPAY.DBF is changed accordingly. E.g

If the user enters 201501 the path will become P:/xx/2015/01/xxPAY.dbf. If the user enters 201402 the path will become P:/xx/2014/02/xxPAY.dbf

The P: drive is a network drive and also the application is run as an adminstrator. While debugging the program the path seems to be fine always but I would get an error saying "P:/xx/2015/01/xxPAY.dbf" not found. However if I provide the UNC path "\ServerName\xx\2015\01\xxPAY.dbf" the report generates fine. Any thoughts what could be the reason for this behaviour. I am not sure if the code is required but I will post it here anyways :-

```
IF !FILE('P:\IMPORT\Wei-cosmts\'+ ;
        LEFT(ALLT(STR(thisform.yyyymm,6,0)),4)+'\'+ ;
        RIGHT(ALLT(STR(thisform.yyyymm,6,0)),2)+'\'+ ;
        lsPeriod+'pay.dbf')
     =MESSAGEBOX('Can not find '+'P:\IMPORT\Wei-cosmts\'+ ;
        LEFT(ALLT(STR(thisform.yyyymm,6,0)),4)+'\'+ ;
        RIGHT(ALLT(STR(thisform.yyyymm,6,0)),2)+'\'+ ;
        lsPeriod+'pay.dbf'+'. '+CHR(13)+CHR(13)+'Comparison report can not run.',16)
    RETURN .F.
ENDIF
```

Answer (score 0):

If the UNC path works, I'd suggest to use it.

FWIW, the old "mapped drive" feature is pretty useless anyway, just an end-user representation of the "real" (UNC) network address. In your particular case, I'd guess the current Windows user might have one while you are debugging in the IDE, whereas the run-time user, i.e. the "run as" admin account, might have not.

In your code, you would not need to concatenate the calculated path string twice by the way, e.g.

```
Local lcFile
lcFile = "\\ServerNameOrIP\sharedFolder\" + ;
    LEFT(ALLT(STR(thisform.yyyymm,6,0)),4)+'\'+ ;
    RIGHT(ALLT(STR(thisform.yyyymm,6,0)),2)+'\'+ ;
    lsPeriod+'pay.dbf'
If Not File(m.lcFile, 1)
    MessageBox(m.lcFile + " not found")
...
```

Comment: One problem I see with following the UNC path approach is that it will require a code change every time the server is moved. Seems like running the command prompt as an administrator and mapping the drive using a command "net use P: \\servername\folder" could possible resolve the issue. But that is something I will have to try

Comment: In practice, most people would avoid hard-coded path strings in their code anyway, i.e, keep those outside in a "config" file somewhere in the user profile %AppData% folder for example. In VFP you could actually use an external `config.fpw` file, or a more scalable place like an XML, INI etc., or even a TXT file. Creating mapped drive dynamically at runtime would not unlikely cause troubles because those are an end-user feature, only a few letters available, and you cannot know whether "P" already exists on a certain client